# Get current position of instantiated prefab

Tags: unity, c#

I wrote two little scripts to manage platform spawning. 
1st - is attached to the Spawner gameObject. It's uset to spawn new platform.
2nd - is something like Platform Manager which not extend MonoBehaviour.

I want to set Spawner to create new platforms after old one goes off screen. But I dont know how to get current position of instantiated platform for example to check if platform is actualy off the screen.

Below my scripts:

1st. Spawner

```
void Update() {

    NewPlatform();
}

public void NewPlatform() {

    if (active) {
        newTransform = transform;
        PlatformManager.Instantiate(prefabs[Random.Range(0, prefabs.Length)], newTransform.position);              
    }
}
```

}

2nd. PlatformManager

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlatformManager {

public static GameObject Instantiate(GameObject prefab, Vector3 pos) {

    GameObject instance = null;

    instance = GameObject.Instantiate(prefab);
    instance.transform.position = pos;

    return instance;
}
```

}

Briefly - haw can I get current position of instantiated object (or other parameters) from Spawner script?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You already have it. `newTransform.position`

Comment: something isn't adding up. You may want to go back to the whiteboard

Comment: But this script is attached to Spawner which is not movinng. So if check position for example in Update method:
 `Debug.Log("Current position: " + newTransform.position); `
it always return 0,0,0.

Comment: I understood that.  The reason you are having trouble is because you are on the wrong path.  You need to backtrack, not move forward.  I know it is hard to do, but i sincerely suggest deleting these 2 scripts, calling it a day, and looking at it fresh tomorrow.  That is what I would do.

Comment: `instance.transform.position = pos - transform.position` should do the trick. Or just use `instance.transform.position = transform.TransformPoint(pos)`

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching a script to your platform instances. Then in that scripts `Start()` method use `Debug.Log` to log the parent platforms `Transform`